# Is it sign of confirmation if I am asked to submit salary related documents after interview?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I had an interview last weekend and got salary discussion with HR as well on the same day. I was asked to submit salary related documents on the next day. 
But I didn't hear from them till now.

Can I expect offer letter from them?

Comment: What do you mean by "Salary Related Documents"? Banking information? Shouldn`t it be part of contract signing procedure?

Comment: "But I didn't hear from them till now."  Does this mean you just heard from them?  What did they say?

Comment: @Strader they ask for the last three months salary slips..

Comment: @sf02 No I didn't hear from them after submission of the documents..

Comment: Most likely HR was advancing HR bureaucracy, while the hiring process needs approval steps from management/director/CEO/etc. You might have sent stuff that nobody has opened so far. Don't try to think of it as a sign.

Comment: Why would a company, who is offering to hire you, ask for your current pay stubs?  That doesn't sound legitimate.

Comment: @SayanBasu in this case position location would help this question, first time i am hearing about this requirement :)

Answer (score 6):

> Can I expect offer letter from them?

**Do not expect anything**

It's a good sign, but some companies ask for documentation from multiple candidate then choose just one of them.

**Never expect, or act as if, you have an offer until the ink is dry on whatever employment contract is sent over**

Comment: Good answer. I would add to this that OP should keep their options open and keep applying and job-hunting other prospect jobs, *just* in case this one does not land.

Answer (score 3):

As said elsewhere, you can't expect anything.

What concerns me more is them asking, not only for proof of wages, but 3 months worth.  Personally, I wouldn't give that information to a current employer much less a prospective one. The only two reasons I know of why they would want this information is they are under the delusion that your past wages should affect what they pay you. The other is to prove that you were telling the truth about your employment and/or wages before.

The money you make at a former employer should have no bearing on your value to subsequent companies. There are many reasons why a person would make significantly less at a previous job including your personal financial situation necessitating you to accept a lower wage than you otherwise would. That's just one.

I wouldn't (and don't) give anyone (much less a prospective employer) documentation about previous employers unless they are unable to verify employment themselves (such as a going out of business). Furthermore, I don't discuss how much I've made during negotiations.

People have been conditioned to believe that interviewing is a one-way street and that they're doing you a favor.  Remember that you're interviewing them too.  You're not Oliver Twist asking for "more?".  Everything goes both ways, which is one reason you need to ask questions in an interview as well, but I digress.

If I were asked what my previous wages were, I'd ask them if they were prepared to tell me how much they currently pay other people doing the job and/or previous employees.  Likewise with documentation.I'd ask if they were willing to provide documentation about how much others have made.  It makes the point that it's a two-way street. Additionally, you giving information could even violate a non-disclosure agreement (NDA), depending on how it's written and the state.

TL;DR - Don't expect anything from a future or current employer that goes beyond what's already written. You can hope, but don't expect. And I wouldn't discuss previous wages much less actually give them documentation.

Comment: Great answer.   It drives me crazy how some companies expect you to jump through all sorts of hoops with the hopes of mayyyyyyyybe getting an offer

Comment: Posting in March 2022: Companies who expect you to jump through all sorts of hoops learn quickly that all the good candidates find a job elsewhere. Plus the passable ones, and many of the barely acceptable ones.

Comment: @gnasher729 it's definitely a workers' market these days